# stripping random number with substr problem

Tags: php, random, substring

Using a random number to be included with another character. Then I want to strip out the random number and just leave the other character. I have this code that generates the random number (8 characters long) consistently. If you hit your refresh button multiple times, the “ID” field disappears even though the “Random Number” plus “ID” are still there. Not sure what is happening to the random number on refresh in the substr function.
This is the code:

```
// Begin Create Random ID Code /////////////////////////////////////////

function gRanStr1() {
    $length1 = 8;
    $characters = “0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ”;

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length1; $p++) {
        $lcrs1 .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
    }

    $lcrs9 = str_replace(' ', '', $lcrs9);

    return $lcrs1;

}

// End Create Random ID Code /////////////////////////////////////////

// Begin Decode Random ID Code /////////////////////////////////////////

$TrkR99 = "c";

$ResHeadID = gRanStr1() . $TrkR99;

$ResHeadID = preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',$ResHeadID);

echo "”;
echo $ResHeadID . ” = echo of Random Number plus ID“;

for($i=0; $i<strlen($ResHeadID); $i++){
    if(!is_numeric(substr($ResHeadID, $i, 1))){
        $Index1 = $i;
        break;
    }
}

if ($ResHeadID == "") {
    "";
} else {
    $ResHeadID = preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',$ResHeadID);
    $TrkRa1 = substr($ResHeadID, $Index1 + 8, 1);
}

$dTrkRes = $TrkRa1;

echo $TrkRa1 . " = echo of ID after random number stripped.“;

echo “”;

// End Decode Random ID Code /////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors.  I strongly suggest you use a syntax highlighting editor like Notepad++.  Also, don't use smart quotes.

Comment: Sorry to say, but your code is a real big mess. Variable namings purpose seems to secure the job of the programer, some lines are simply useless (like `$lcrs9 = str_replace(' ', '', $lcrs9); # what for? there is no $lcrs9!`) or `echo ""; # there is the smart quote!` or `if ( $ResHeadID == "") { ""; /* WTF? */ }` Whenever posting a question please provide something **readable**

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems is in the line
`$ResHeadID = preg_replace('/[\s]+/',' ',$ResHeadID);`

Your random numbers may start with a digit. if this is the case the preg replace will have some offset and kill your ID.

Your random string has a fixed length, so i'd suggest to simply do
`$TrkRa1 = substr($ResHeadID, 8);` in your else clause.

Comment: Thank you very much. I cleaned up the code and your fix works perfectly. Thank you again.

Comment: happy to help, it would be nice if you'd mark this question as solved/my answer as accepted :)